# Really slow ssd performance

Tags: hard-drive, kubuntu, ssd

So I installed Kubuntu 15.04 on a samsung 840 evo ssd, the system works fine but I did a test  to see the speed of the ssd.

```
hdparm -t /dev/sdb
```

gives me about 30MB/s, when it is supposed to give me around 500MB/s.
I have another hard disk connected to the system where I mount /home, if I do a test on this drive it gives me around 120MB/s, which is expected.

What can be causing this slow speed?